# MS Unit Test and CustomAttribute behavior

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes

I have a lone `[TestMethod]` which uses a Sql Server table as its `[DataSource]`. I also have a custom attribute on that test method which does some stuff in a database.

This custom attribute looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{        
    public CustomAttribute(int number)
    {
        //do stuff with number
    }
}
```

The whole test method looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[CustomAttribute(10)] //This value is different in each test method
[DataSource(connectionStuff)] //This returns 4 rows
public void Test(){
    //do test
}
```

When I run the test and trace what's going on in the CustomAttribute, it's constructor gets called 60 times, which is 56 times more than I would expect.

I added this to the attribute to debug:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{        
    static bool check = false;

    public CustomAttribute(int number)
    {
        if(check) return;
        check = true;
        //do stuff with number
    }
}
```

Now the rest of the constructor only runs 4 times, as originally expected.

Can somebody explain to me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Member attributes are evaluated *once* when the type is created. So when your test class is first references, the type is created, and all `[CustomAttribute]` calls are evaluated. This is regardless of which methods are called, i.e. regardless of which test method is executed.

Attributes in .NET are only metadata, attached to types or members. They are not meant to modify the member or be invoked when the member is accessed. So you should definitely not have them *do* anything. You should only use them to *store* information.

Comment: I mostly get what you're saying. I still can't figure out where each evaluation is coming from though. Right now the attribute only exists on one method in one class, so what's with the 60 calls?.

Comment: just the one, with 4 iterations.